# xcopy directories and subdirectories recursively and filter only filenames by extension

Tags: batch-file, filtering, filenames, xcopy

Here is what i have for now:

```
xcopy "c:\projects\SampleProject" "c:\temp\copytest" /E /H /EXCLUDE:elist.txt
```

It does all the job i need except filtering filenames by extensions.

For example: copy all `*.exe` files from `c:\temp\copytest` and subdirectories.

How to do that?

Answer (score 47):

I happened to need this too, and found out that if you want to xcopy files with specific type to a new folder keeping the current folder structure you need only to do this

```
xcopy [SourcePath]*.mp3 [DestinationPath]  /sy
```

> **/s:** Copies directories and subdirectories, unless they are empty. If
>   you omit /s, xcopy works within a single directory.
>
> **/y** : Suppresses prompting to confirm that you want to overwrite an
>   existing destination file

[Documentation](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/xcopy.mspx?mfr=true)

Comment: When copying projects, `/D` statement is also useful. It orders CMD to only copy files that are newer than their destination opposite.

Answer (score 3):

Something like:

```
@echo off
setlocal
set DIR=
set OUTPUTDIR=C:\Documents and Settings\<username>\Desktop\sandbox1\output
for /R %DIR% %%a in (*.mp3) do xcopy "%%a" "%OUTPUTDIR%"
```

See (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490909.aspx)

Comment: what if I wanted to copy .txt files in addition to .mp3 files?

Answer (score 0):

I needed the same procedure (copy folders with exclude filter) and used the example of @pollirrata.

One thing I have to mention that in order to copy a folder I needed to specify a backslash for destination directory to suppress prompting a question.

So I ended with the following syntax:

```
xcopy SourceFolder DestinationFolder\ /EXCLUDE:exclude.txt
```

Contents of the `exclude.txt` file:

```
.mp3
```

To copy only files with specific extension (e.g. `*.exe`) I used

```
xcopy SourceFolder\*.exe DestinationFolder\
```